# Field accountRepository in com.banking.account.query.infrastructure.handlers.AccountEventHandler required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, microservices

estoy haciendo un curso de microservicios con kafka,mysql,mongodb,spring boot con lenguaje java , y la conexión a mongodb si me funciona pero la de mysql me da este error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field accountRepository in com.banking.account.query.infrastructure.handlers.AccountEventHandler required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

He mirado si los dockers estaban parados y no lo estan, he comprobado si me loggee bien y si ,probe soluciones de esta plataforma como añadir "@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")" y me daba error y sinceramente ya no se que hacer, al principio como me daba problemas con el hibernate ,lo añadí al pom y se soluciono pero sigue saliendo el error de arriba ,y no se si es por el hibernate ,o alguna falla de codigo que sea muy antiguo y hay que cambiarlo
Este es el codigo de la clase que me falla:

```
package com.banking.account.query.infrastructure.handlers;

import com.banking.account.common.events.AccountClosedEvent;
import com.banking.account.common.events.AccountOpenedEvent;
import com.banking.account.common.events.FundsDepositedEvent;
import com.banking.account.common.events.FundsWithdrawnEvent;
import com.banking.account.query.domain.AccountRepository;
import com.banking.account.query.domain.BankAccount;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AccountEventHandler implements EventHandler{
    //acceso a los objetos a la instancia de la bbdd
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public void on(AccountOpenedEvent event) {
        //crear objeto backaccount e insertarlo en la bbdd
        var bankAccount= BankAccount.builder()
        .id(event.getId())
        .accountHolder(event.getAccountHolder())
        .creationDate(event.getCreatedDate())
        .accountType(event.getAccountType())
        .balance(event.getOpeningBalance())
        .build();
        accountRepository.save(bankAccount);


    }

    @Override
    public void on(FundsDepositedEvent event) {
        var bankAccount=accountRepository.findById(event.getId());
        if (bankAccount.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        //balance actual
        var currentBalance=bankAccount.get().getBalance();
        var latestBalance=currentBalance + event.getAmount();//balance final sumando el dinero introducido
        bankAccount.get().setBalance(latestBalance);//guardar valor nuevo
        accountRepository.save(bankAccount.get());
    }

    @Override
    public void on(FundsWithdrawnEvent event) {
        var bankAccount=accountRepository.findById(event.getId());
        if (bankAccount.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        var currentBalance=bankAccount.get().getBalance();
        var latestBalance=currentBalance - event.getAmount();
        bankAccount.get().setBalance(latestBalance);
        accountRepository.save(bankAccount.get());
    }

    @Override
    public void on(AccountClosedEvent event) {
        accountRepository.deleteById(event.getId());

    }
}
```

Clase principal:

package com.banking.account.query;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QueryApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     SpringApplication.run(QueryApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: El fallo te dice que cuando Spring está generando un objeto `AccountEventHandler`, intenta iyectar la dependencia `AccountRepository`. Pero esa clase, a su vez, tiene como dependencia un objeto `entityManagerFactory` que no sabe cómo obtener. ¿Cómo tienes declarada la clase principal (el punto de entrada)?. Cómo has configurado las conexiones a tu base de datos MySQL?

Comment: la clase principal como punto de entrada no lo entendí bien ,si es la que ejecuta el proyecto se llama "QueryApplication" y la conexion a la bbdd lo he hecho mediante un documento .yml y un docker que contiene dicha bbdd

Comment: ¿Pero cómo tienes anotada esa clase? ¿Puedes añadirla a la pregunta, usando [edit]?

Comment: package com.banking.account.query;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QueryApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(QueryApplication.class, args);
 }

}